# Docker run on a default installed git path instead of working directory on windows

Tags: python, docker, automation, gherkin

Working Directory : C:\Users\Test.users\PycharmProjects\qa

Below code store in run.sh file

```
docker run --rm --shm-size=2g -v $PWD :/qa --name $DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME $DOCKER_IMAG
```

Running test case from powershell.

```
./run.sh -f 123_FE_Test.txt
```

It display below error while running test case from the powershell.

```
[ ERROR ] Parsing 'C:/Program Files/Git/Test/FeatureTest/suites/regression/123_FE_Test.txt' failed: Data source does not exist.
```

Comment: Windows uses batch scripts .bat and .cmd. Also from your error it looks file path related.

Comment: we can run .sh file in powershell in windows

Comment: Find the solution : run your .sh file in power shell. echo docker run --rm --shm-size=2g -v $PWD :/qa --name $DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME $DOCKER_IMAG the command and whatever result display copy it and run that in to command prompt.